# Google analytics userId configuration

Tags: google-analytics

currently want to track unique users in GA (remember their session, etc). Having the problem of where to place the userId code inside the tracking code?

Is it correct to place it in between create and send? or does it matter? will it have a negative effect if I place it before create or after send?

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Beginner level with GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in the `create` command via the optional [`fieldsObject`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#create), or you can [`set`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#set) it on the tracker after it's created (but before the pageview is sent).

You *cannot* put it before the create command, and if you put it after the pageview is sent, it'll be too late and won't apply to that hit.

In other words, either of these two variations will work:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {userId: USER_ID});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

or:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'userId', USER_ID);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```